# How to configure RedisSessionStateProvider to use Redis sentinel?

Tags: asp.net, redis, session-state, stackexchange.redis

I have a demo ASP.NET app with the session store configured to use a single Redis master node using the [Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider) nuget (config below).

As a next step I would like to change my Redis store to be high availability by adding slave and sentinel nodes. Question (1): does the RedisSessionStateProvider support this, and (2) if so, how do I configure RedisSessionStateProvider to refer to sentinel nodes.

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisProvider" timeout="240" cookieless="UseCookies" cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" useHostingIdentity="true">
  <providers>           
    <add name="RedisProvider" 
                 type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider, Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider"
                     host="127.0.0.1"
                     port="6379"
                     accessKey=""
                     ssl="false" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question quickly... remove host, port, accessKey, and ssl attributes from the provider config and add connectionString. Enter the correct connection string information for your case: ie - "192.168.1.10:6379,192.168.1.11:6379,192.168.1.12:6379,ssl=false,password=My_Super_Secret_Password". Since you are using a cluster configuration all node passwords have to be the same for this to work correctly. You also need to provide the applicationName attribute like applicationName="TestApp" so your web.config should look something like the following:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" cookieName="_web.ss" customProvider="RedisSessionStateProvider" cookieless="false" timeout="10080">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="RedisSessionStateProvider" 
         type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
         applicationName="TestApp"   
         connectionString="192.168.1.10:6379,192.168.1.11:6379,192.168.1.12:6379,ssl=false,password=My_Super_Secret_Password"  />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Hope this help :)